# Adding Image in fc-day-number of fullcalendar.js doesn't work after publishing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iis, fullcalendar

My requirement was to add an icon in the same line in which the date is displayed in fullcalendar.cs.

Since i didn't found any event which gave me exact result i decided to go and edit fullcalendar.js.

I had used cell.prepend to add the images but that moved the images on the top and day numbers were coming on the 2nd line.

```
html += "<div class='fc-day-number'><img class='fc-state-default' src=\"../../icon.png\"/><label style=\"horizontal-align: left; margin-right:22px\">   Virtual/Synchronous</label>    " + cellDate.getDate() + "</div>";
```

This above line work perfectly when i am running the application through visual studio. Image is displayed as expected
But when i published the same code in IIS then then images does come up in the hosted application.

I do checked all the IIS setting , but not able to figure out if this is because of IIS setting or any css of **fullcalendar.js**

[While debugging:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhKGr.png)

[After Hosting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4imVr.png)

Comment: Are you sure the image file was definitely deployed to the right location in the IIS server, along with the rest of the code?

Comment: P.S. You almost certainly don't need to modify fullCalendar's source code for this. You didn't say which version of fullCalendar you're using, but in the newest v5 there are several callbacks you could potentially use to inject this HTML - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks. There is broadly equivalent functionality in the earlier versions too - check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks ADyson and @ding Peng , i even tried with day render cell but it was having the same issue, then i found out that i had to add a root directory path after before the image path. Then only this images were working. I cannot mark the answer as i still have reputation less than 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I think this is because IIS not find icon.png. You can try to create an images directory in the project to store icon.png:

[image]

**Note that the images directory is in the root directory of the project.**

Modify the path of the picture in html:

```
<img class='fc-state-default' src=\"~/images/icon.png\"/>
```

Comment: This was helpful , there was a script for my application to goto root directory and then i had to add the image path. So Yes after adding the root directory to image path it worked.